# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: pUnk

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2019

I have upgraded my visual studio to visual studio 2019 and now sometime with few 
files while trying to check in code to TFS its giving me error:

> Value cannot
>   be null. Parameter name: pUnk

I tried even to delete whole source code and downloaded it again but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like its an issue with Visual Studio Preview 2019:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/398508/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-punk-when-chec.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case vs2019 Preview hasn't been near my machine but I encountered this in vs2017. 
Couldn't get rid, but luckily I hadn't uninstalled vs2015 from my machine and was able to check in using that. 
Bit of an edge case workaround maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2017. I had multiple instance of visual studio and one instance Licensed with different account (admin). Closing other instance of visual studio solved my problem.